# How to merge array of objects element in javascript using common property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge

```
     const data = [
  {
    date: "2021-05-17",
    meals: [{ name: "jon", breakFast: 1, lunch: 2, dinner: 2 }],
  },
  {
    date: "2021-05-17",
    meals: [{ name: "Bob", breakFast: 3, lunch: 4, dinner: 5 }],
  },
  {
    date: "2021-05-18",
    meals: [{ name: "Boo", breakFast: 3, lunch: 4, dinner: 5 }],
  },
];
```

I have an array of objects. There has different date and meals(array of objects). Is it possible to show all same date meals together?

Like this one.

```
  const data = [
  {
    date: "2021-05-17",
    meals: [
      { name: "jon", breakFast: 1, lunch: 2, dinner: 2 },
      { name: "Bob", breakFast: 3, lunch: 4, dinner: 5 },
    ],
  },
  {
    date: "2021-05-18",
    meals: [{ name: "Boo", breakFast: 3, lunch: 4, dinner: 5 }],
  },
];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group an array of objects by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key)

Answer (score 2):

```js
const data = [{
        date: "2021-05-17",
        meals: [{
            name: "jon",
            breakFast: 1,
            lunch: 2,
            dinner: 2
        }],
    },
    {
        date: "2021-05-17",
        meals: [{
            name: "Bob",
            breakFast: 3,
            lunch: 4,
            dinner: 5
        }],
    },
    {
        date: "2021-05-18",
        meals: [{
            name: "Boo",
            breakFast: 3,
            lunch: 4,
            dinner: 5
        }],
    },
];

let res = {};
data.forEach(x => {
    if (!res[x.date]) {
        res[x.date] = {
            ...x
        };
    } else {
        res[x.date].meals = [...res[x.date].meals, ...x.meals];

    }
});

console.log(Object.values(res));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate all the `data` and search if the `result` array contains the date. If not, create the new item with the date. Then just push the meals data inside.

```js
const data = [{date: "2021-05-17",meals: [{ name: "jon", breakFast: 1, lunch: 2, dinner: 2 }],},{date: "2021-05-17",meals: [{ name: "Bob", breakFast: 3, lunch: 4, dinner: 5 }],},{date: "2021-05-18",meals: [{ name: "Boo", breakFast: 3, lunch: 4, dinner: 5 }],},];

const result = [];
data.forEach(d => {
  let i = result.findIndex(e => e.date === d.date) + 1 
  || result.push({date: d.date, meals: []});
  result[i - 1].meals.push(...d.meals);
})

console.log(result);
```